# Get field (list type) label in a twig template

Tags: theming, entities

I have a content type (*appel_offre*) with a *field_categorie_avis* field, which is a list type with these values.

- ouvert | Ouvert toute l'année
- restreint | Restreint 24h
- concurrence | Appel public à concurrence

In the node--appel-offre.html.twig template, I want to print this field but I only get the key, not the value. For example, for *Appel public à concurrence*, I always get *concurrence*.

I am using `node.field_categorie_avis.value`. Is there another way to get the same value?

Comment: what does it spit out if you use dump() on the field?

Comment: Hello and happy new years !

Comment: Happy New year to you too!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
{{ content.field_categorie_avis[0]['#markup'] }}
```

to display label.

Dont miss the `[0]` because drupal always store items in array in case of field size limit change.

Comment: Very useful. I was struggling with this for last couple of hours.

Comment: This did not work for me in Drupal 8.9. Instead, use: `element['#object'].field_name.setting('allowed_values')[element['#object'].field_name.value]`

Answer (score 0):

Came across this same issue, none of the proposed solutions worked... in a node template what worked was:

```
node.field_myselect_list.fieldDefinition.itemDefinition.settings.allowed_values[node.field_myselect_list.value]
```